# How to define a blank-independent macro

Tags: macros

How would I define a macro `\test` , e.g. using `\def\test#1{...}`, that can be used in the two following ways? The usage without a blank

```
\test{A}This is some text
```

as well as the usage with a blank

```
\test{A} This is some text
```

should yield the same typeset result:

> A: This is some text

This would help me in making life easier while writing my free physics text.

Comment: `\def\test#1{#1: \ignorespaces}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code

```
\newcommand\test[1]{#1:~\ignorespaces}
```

will do what you want. The space should be part of the replacement text, as you seem to want it; with `\ignorespace`, spaces following the argument will be gobbled.

Answer (score 6):

Package `xspace` can be your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{#1:\xspace}
\begin{document}
\test{A}This is some text

\test{A} This is some text
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

However, `xspace` does not add a space before punctuation characters, for example, its usage is intended for stuff inside text. Manuels's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315505/how-to-define-a-blank-independent-macro/315507#comment769884_315505) or egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315508/16967) are probably better in this case, because it always sets one space and ignores additional spaces.

Comment: Hm, I already use 55 packages, adding one more is dangerous. I'd prefer an explicit code...

Comment: @MotionMountain “adding one more is dangerous” Why?

Comment: @MotionMountain The grade of danger heavily depends on the packages. There are packages, small, quite independent, which post not much of a danger, there are packages, quite interfering with LaTeX internals or conflict with other packages. Package `xspace` belongs rather to the first category.

Comment: OK, I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: xspace loads without problems, but I need \ignorespaces nevertheless, as my code already adds a space.